# Screen overlaying issue with Cordova + Angular app

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I've got an app developed with AngularJS + Cordova/Ionic.
System set up:

- AngularJS
- Cordova 9
- Ionic 1

The issue: 
The app is basically an online shop where you have different product groups. You can go inside the group and choose a product there.
After a few page navigations, when I navigate to the previous page, the of the things happens:

- A previous in the navigation stack overlays half of the screen of the current page.
- Current page duplicates and overlays on the previous page.
  When it happens, both of the screens are available and you can scroll for example.

The issue appears on iPhone X and higher only. Android works fine.

What I found in internet didn't give me a clear answer about this issue and how to solve it.
Here are the links for resources:

- [Ionic app back button causes previous state screens to overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39071361/ionic-app-back-button-causes-previous-state-screens-to-overlap)
- https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-iphone-screen-overlap-on-page-navigation/37900/15
- [Content overlaps in Ionic 1 app for IOS version 11 and above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52003399/content-overlaps-in-ionic-1-app-for-ios-version-11-and-above)

[image]
[image]

Could you help me to find the reason? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time, the solution was found. In my case, it was a cache issue

when initiating app config you set
`$ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(XXX);`

`maxCache(3)` was an optimal number for me and now it works without any issues